# Video not working after clicking home button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have create a view that contain a `MPMoviePlayer` to play a video on screen. It work fine when i open it the first time and when I go to another view and come back.
The video does not seem to work when I left my application by clicking home button and come back to the application. Is it a way to make it run?

here is the code[I put it in `viewDidLoad` ]:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                         pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,480,320)];

    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

Comment: How are you doing that? Some code will be helpful.

Comment: i have updated my code, Any idea?